# GalleryView Item Change Listener

Tags: android, galleryview

I want to detect the gallery view slide to next item in Android like if gallery view current index is 0 if slide the gallery view to next image i want to detect this event item change listener on slide event in android!I have no idea for this concept pls help me any one Thanks!

Comment: Nice user name you got there :) .. are you looking for onItemchangedListener?

Comment: i want to detect event the gallery view slide to current item to next item how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found my answer. Using  `setOnItemSelectedListener` slide or keypress it is easy to find current item focused:

```
g.setOnItemSelectedListener( new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
        Log.v("Changed----->", ""+pos);
        change_position=pos;
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For that Purpose you needs To create a custom gallery and override onFling() method of GestureDetector class. and in that method you can easily detect your view sliding directions.

Comment: Thanks for answering i am find solution another way!